# How to style React mdx rendered elements with CSS module?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-css-modules

I'm building blog with React where post files are `.mdx` and I'm using `gatsby-plugin-mdx`'s `MDXRenderer` to render them as HTML. I'm styling with `.module.scss` but I can't use module inside rendered HTML is there a way like arguments or function?

```
import * as React from "react";
import { graphql } from "gatsby";
import { MDXRenderer } from "gatsby-plugin-mdx";
import Layout from "../../components/Layout";

interface DataType {
  mdx: {
    frontmatter: {
      title: string;
      date: string;
    };
    body: string;
  };
}

const BlogPost = ({ data }: { data: DataType }) => {
  return (
    <Layout pageTitle={data.mdx.frontmatter.title}>
      <p>{data.mdx.frontmatter.date}</p>
      <MDXRenderer>{data.mdx.body}</MDXRenderer>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export const query = graphql`
  query ($id: String) {
    mdx(id: { eq: $id }) {
      frontmatter {
        title
        date(formatString: "MMMM D, YYYY")
      }
      body
    }
  }
`;

export default BlogPost;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this inside the MDXProvider using the components attribute (for example in your layout component).

```js
import { myP } from './style/mdx.module.css';

<MDXProvider
  components={{
    p: props => <p {...props} style={myP} />,
  }}
>
```

Incidentally, you can also map tags to React components if you'd like even more finecontrol.